# Determinant of $Z^TZ$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, matrix-theory

If one is looking at the characteristic polynomial of the $m \times m$ dimensional matrix $Z^TZ$ then apparently the coefficient of $(-1)^{m-k}$ in it can be written as, $\sum_{U \subset [m], V \subset [m], |U|=|V| = k}det^2(Z_{U,V})$ where by $Z_{U,V}$ one means the sumbatrix of $Z$ corresponding to the $k$ rows and columns of it given by the index sets $U$ and $V$ respectively.

Can someone kindly give a reference to a proof of this?
(Or type in the proof if its short!)

Comment: Looks like it can be proved with the Cauchy-Binet formula. I suppose you mean $\lambda^{m-k}$ rather than $(-1)^{m-k}$.

Comment: Yes, I meant the same thing. Could you kindly give some more details?

Comment: Yep, you should be able to get it by combining Proposition 1' and Theorem 4 in my post at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1752326/ .

Answer (score 3):

I'll prove that the coefficient of $(-\lambda)^{m-k}$ in the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ is given by $\sum_{|U|=|V|=k} \det A_{U,V}\det B_{V,U}$. By the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), this sum is equal to $\sum_{|U|=k} \det((AB)_{U,U})$.

This latter quantity can be proved to be equal to the coefficient of $(-\lambda)^{m-k}$ in the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ by a combinatorial argument: to obtain a term of degree $m-k$ in the Laplace expansion of the characteristic polynomial, you need to select (in all possible ways) a permutation with at least $m-k$ fixed points, take $-\lambda$ terms from those fixed points and non-$\lambda$ terms from the other $k$. Summing over all possible subsets $[m]\setminus U$ of $m-k$ entries, you get that sum.

There must be a more elegant way to make this last argument, but that should be the idea at least.